# CoreData - storing an integer that updates on button tap

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, int

I am new to CoreData. I built out a very simple counter interface that advances the number by 1 every time the view is tapped. Very straightforward. Need to implement CoreData so that the number persists next time it's opened.

**Here is my code**

*class level properties*

```
var timer = Int()
var name = Int()
let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

*viewDidLoad*

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    do {
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Model")
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

        for item in results{
            let name = item.valueForKey("counter") as! Int
            print("The counter # saved in Core Data is: \(name)")
            counterOutlet.text = "\(name)"

            // Updated
            if name > timer {
                 timer = name
            }
        }

    }
    catch {
        print("Error retrieving from Core Data.")
    }
}
```

*View Tapped (to increase the counter, and save to CD*

```
@IBAction func tapGestureRecognizerTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    timer += 1
    print(timer)
    counterOutlet.text = "\(timer)"

    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

    // Add stuff to CD
    let mySavedCounter = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Model", inManagedObjectContext: context)
    mySavedCounter.setValue(timer, forKey: "counter")


    // Add the info to the entity!
    do {
        try context.save()
    }
    catch {
        print("Error saving to Core Data.")
    }
}
```

**My data model**
[image: xcdatamodel]

When I load the app for the first time ever, counter is at 0 (as it should be.) I can tap the view to increment the counter by 1. Works fine.

When I hard close the app, I reopen it to see the value I left off at is still there! (great!!) The console log shows the following: (i closed the app once I got to 15.)

```
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 1
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 2
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 3
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 4
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 5
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 6
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 7
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 8
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 9
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 10
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 11
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 12
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 13
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 14
The counter # saved in Core Data is: 15
```

**Now for the problem that I need to debug:**

Once I tap the view, the counter resets down to 0, and increments up from there. Not incrementing up from 15, as it should!

*How can I fix this bug to make the counter increment onto the saved number (in this case, 15.) Additionally, I created an NSManagedObject subclass, but don't seem to be utilizing it. The above code was created using a couple of youtube tutorials. Can this code be optimized by using the subclass? Is it bad practice to save this counter to CD everytime the view is tapped?*

Comment: if the only thing you're trying to persist is the counter, why wouldn't you just use NSUserDefaults instead of bringing CoreData stack to the app ?

Comment: @Eugene Zhenya Gordin - the short answer to that is i just want practice with coredata. thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

In viewDidLoad you set counterOutlet.text to name.
You also have to set the timer to name. The updated code in viewDidLoad looks like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    do {
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Model")
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)

    for item in results{
        let name = item.valueForKey("counter") as! Int
        print("The counter # saved in Core Data is: \(name)")
        counterOutlet.text = "\(name)"
        timer = name
    }

}
catch {
    print("Error retrieving from Core Data.")
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong code written in 'tapGestureRecognizerTapped' method, you should not not insert new object into core database each time after tap. I would suggest to insert object once in 'viewDidLoad' when inserted object count is zero otherwise don't insert. Now you have to get the saved value into CoreDatabse and update the value and save it back.

Comment: Mind posting an answer with code I should try to accomplish this? Trying to tackle this CoreData learning curve as best as I can. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're saving and fetching data-- but you're not using previously saved data to update the value of `timer`. So it starts at zero every time because you don't tell it to be anything else when the app starts.

If you plan to loop through all of the entries after fetching, you could get the value of `timer` by adding a line like this to the loop:

```
if name > timer {
    timer = name
}
```

Then `timer` would get whatever the maximum saved value is, and count up from there. If you don't plan to loop through all the entries, you could use `reduce` on the fetched array to find the max value.

Whether saving a value each time is good or bad depends on what your app is supposed to be doing. Do you want an entry for each value, or just a single value? In the former case, this is fine, but in the latter you're creating entries you don't need.

Comment: I just want a single value. After reading your comment and Santosh's, looks like I'm doing this all wrong. I just need to add the object once, and update its value to CD. Correct? - EDIT: I edited my question above with your if statement. That fixed the error of the counter resetting back to zero, however, I still need to fix this so it's CD efficient.

Comment: Can you provide any code guidance on how to prevent new entries from being created for each value? I just want a single value stored in CD that updates every time. Thanks!

Comment: You know how to do a fetch request. Fetch the existing entry and see what it is. Then change that value and save changes.